# How to use PGProperty with HikariDataSource?

Tags: java, postgresql, hikaricp, jdbi

I am trying to figure out how to use PGProperty properties to configure a hikari data source.

This works fine:

```
final String jdbcUrl = String.format(
            "jdbc:postgresql://%s:%s/%s?ApplicationName=%s",
            configuration.getDatabaseHost(),
            configuration.getDatabasePort(),
            configuration.getDatabaseName(),
            configuration.getDatabaseAppName());
hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
hikariDataSource.setUsername(configuration.getDatabaseUsername());
hikariDataSource.setPassword(configuration.getDatabasePassword());
hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(configuration.getDatabaseMaximumPoolSize());
```

but I'd like to be able to use PGProperty to avoid building up the JDBC url by hand as above. When I try this:

```
hikariDataSource.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_HOST.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseHost());
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_PORT.getName(), configuration.getDatabasePort());
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_DBNAME.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseName());
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.APPLICATION_NAME.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseAppName());
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.USER.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseUsername());
hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PASSWORD.getName(), configuration.getDatabasePassword());
```

I get this error:

```
Property PGHOST does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
```

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGProperty.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql:");
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_HOST.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseHost());
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_PORT.getName(), configuration.getDatabasePort());
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PG_DBNAME.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseName());
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.APPLICATION_NAME.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseAppName());
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.USER.getName(), configuration.getDatabaseUsername());
    hikariDataSource.addDataSourceProperty(PGProperty.PASSWORD.getName(), configuration.getDatabasePassword());
    hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(configuration.getDatabaseMaximumPoolSize());
```